# "resource-request" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

should questions like  [BigO, Running Time, Invariants - Learning Resources](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/569/157) be tagged with [resource-request](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request) ?

This might apply also to many of the big-list questions.

Comment: I think [tag:landu-notation] is sufficient. I think it can be reasonable to make BigO a synonym for that, but the rest are not much related.

Comment: Do you see a difference with [tag:reference-request]?